# Handling Cosmos view in USQL

Tags: u-sql, cosmos

I was just exploring the USQL and thought one scenario where in I need reuse the existing Cosmos (scope) view in my USQL.
First  thing , is it possible to consume the Scope view in USQL?
If its possible then how we can do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please use the Microsoft internal stackoverflow for Cosmos and SCOPE related questions in the future?

Secondly, you will not be able to call into SCOPE code from U-SQL. You will be able to mix SCOPE scripts and U-SQL scripts in your pipeline, but each needs to be standalone.

Comment: Sure Michael.Thanks.

Comment: No worries... if the answer was addressing your question, please mark it. Thanks